# Delete element from GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, applet, japplet

how can I delete element from GridBagElement ?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BsDW.jpg

[image]
I want to remove the selected item by clicking on the button.
How can I send the name of the selected item as a parameter to the action button?

Answer (score 1):

First, you don't delete from GridBagLayout. With swing you add Components to a Container, and you remove them from a Container. 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#remove%28java.awt.Component%29

To select the Green Panel you can Register an ActionListener or MouseListener for this Panel.
The MouseListener delivers the MouseEvent. 
The MouseEvent can get you the Source with getSource, which is the green Panel.
And that panel can be removed.

A simple example snippet:

```
final JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
JPanel greenPanel = new JPanel();
greenPanel.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
  @Override
  public void ActionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    int answer = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Delete?");
    if(answer == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
      mainPanel.remove(e.getSource());
    }
  }
});
mainPanel.add(greenPanel);
```

Answer (score 1):

You will want to establish some kind of contract between things like buttons and other controls and your view.

Things that want to modify the view should not be able to do anything you don't want them to (like change the layout for instance).

I'd recommend creating a simple interface which provided access to the operations you want external controls to have access to (like adding, editing, removing).  This you would pass to your controls, there by restricting what the controls can actually do and not exposing unnecessary functionality to them (you wouldn't one of them to remove you main panel ;)).

When you want to remove a selected task, you click the appropriate button, it calls the appropriate "remove" method on your model.

You implementation would then find the selected item (which I assume you either maintain a reference to or have some means to find) and simply remove it from it's parent container.